# What is a significant field for the equals contract (effective java item 8)

Tags: java, class, oop, equals, hashcode

In Effective Java in Item 8 the recommendation is that

> For each significant field in the class to check the corresponding field of the *this* object.

I understand that we can have secondary fields that are calculated by primary fields but what exactly is the meaning of "for each significant field"?   Is the `equals` contract implemented properly only when *all* fields of an object is compared?

If I have e.g. a class `Employee` which has a multitude of fields like id, first and last name, dob, position, location etc all these seem significant but to me it seems that just using the `id` would suffice for a proper and performant `equals` implementation.

Am I wrong on this? Or the `id` I mention is exactly what Bloch means by "significant" fields?

Comment: Since you write the class, you can and have to decide what is "significant". It is ok to compare all fields of an object to validate euqality. Keep in mind to include all significant fields in the `hashCode()`-implementation as well.

Comment: @Turing85: I am trying to understand if the book implies that all the fields excepts those that are calculated by others are meant to be used or not. Yes that is item 9

Comment: If the calculation of secondary properties is deterministic and depends only on primary fields, I would prefer to use only the primary fields. This way, the secondary fields do not have to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee {

    private UUID id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        return id.equals(((Employee)obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

In case of `Employee` is stored into DB, i.e. has `unique id`, then no need to check other fields like `firstName` and `lastName` in `equals`; according to data object comparison, only `id` filed is **significant**.

Answer (score 0):

A significant field is merely one that, if omitted, would result in an incorrect implementation of equals (according to the notion of equality you have defined for instances of your class).

I appreciate that is a bit of a self-referential definition, but that's what it means.

The canonical example of a non-significant field is `String.hashCode`: as you observe, this is calculated from other fields (and lazily), so it would not be appropriate to include in the equality because there is no guarantee that it has been calculated for either of the strings being compared; and, if it has been calculated for both, it tells you nothing more than you already know.

In your case, yes, it sounds like comparing instances using only the `id` would suffice: this is a significant field, the name (etc) is not significant: there should only be one person (little p, as in an actual real human) with a particular id.

It does raise a question of how you would deal with "same id, different name" instances, but this is getting into the realm of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/):

> 1. People have exactly one canonical full name.
> 2. People have exactly one full name which they go by.
> 3. People have, at this point in time, exactly one canonical full name.
> 4. People have, at this point in time, one full name which they go by.
> 5. People have exactly N names, for any value of N.
> 6. (People’s names fit within a certain defined amount of space.)
> 7. People’s names do not change.
> 8. ...

Taking these into consideration, if you want to say "this Person is the same as that Person" (and you want to do that using `equals`), id seems like the only reasonable thing to use.

Comment: You can't have 2 instances with same id and different name by definition of id (I did not downvote and not sure why it happened)

Comment: @Jim in that case you've still not got a problem comparing just by id.

Comment: I was referring to your sentence `It does raise a question of how you would deal with "same id, different name" instances,` I couldn't understand it since a `id` should signify something unique by definition right?

Comment: @Jim i mean that, say, your government identifier (national insurance number, social security number, etc) is fixed, but you can change your name. You could have an instance of `Person` created before and and an instance created after the name change.